# I am looking for a check if user is online script PHP

Tags: php

I was wondering if anybody knows of any PHP script that check if a user is logged in or if the user has sign-out, disconnected or timeout. I am searching for something similar to what this user posted on this website: http://usercake.com/thread.php?id=208. I haven't been able to find the script on Google.

I am able to log in my users, set a log in time and create a session number for them and on log out I am able to set the log out time and delete the session number. But I am not able to check if my user disconnected without logging out, e.g. if the user closed the browser without logging out or if the user navigated outside of the domain. Does anybody know a place where I can find a is-the-user-logged-in script?

Comment: You can switch the PHP session system to use a database, and then checking to see when the user was last online will determine whether they are logged in or not. Remember to always search for your issue prior to asking a question; I'd suggest [this search](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=custom+php+session).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't know for sure in general if a user closed the browser without logging out. Typically, you'd want to have the log in session expire automatically after a period of inactivity to clean up these cases.

Sometimes using javascript on window.onunload https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.onunload?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM%2Fwindow.onunload and send a logout signal that way, but this is unreliable and difficult to get right - you certainly don't want to log them out when they click a link on your site.

I recommend just cleaning up old, inactive sessions on the server periodically.